# Finding the ratio of the areas of two geometric figures

Tags: geometry

Is there a practical way to get the ratio between the area of ​​an equilateral triangle inscribed in a circle and a hexagon whose apothem is the radius of that circle?

```
p1 = {-10, 0};
p2 = {-(10/Sqrt[3]), 10};
p3 = {(10/Sqrt[3]), 10}; 
p4 = {10, 0};
p5 = {(10/Sqrt[3]), -10};
p6 = {(-10/Sqrt[3]), -10};

t1 = {-Cos[30Degree]*10, -Sin[30Degree]*10};
t2 = {Cos[30Degree]*10, -Sin[30Degree]*10};
t3 = {0, 10};
Graphics[
 {Red, Line[{t1, t2, t3, t1}], 
  Purple, Line[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p1}],
  Black, Circle[{0, 0}, 10]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change `Line` to `Polygon` and use built-in functions, e.g.:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], Red, FaceForm[White], 
  a1 = Polygon[{t1, t2, t3, t1}], EdgeForm[Purple], FaceForm[None], 
  a2 = Polygon[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p1}], Black, 
  Circle[{0, 0}, 10]}]
```

So, `Area[a2]/Area[a1]` yields:`16/(3 Sqrt[3] (-3 + Sqrt[3]))`

For regular hexagon:

```
Graphics[{pg1 = Polygon[CirclePoints[1/Sin[Pi/3], 6]], Red, Disk[], 
  Green, pg2 = Polygon@CirclePoints[1, 3]}]
```

[image]

result is: `Area[pg2]/Area[pg1]`: 3/8